# Mysql query order by desc limit in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table target like below

```
id |    subject        |      achievement                |     staff_id
1     Target January          1150000                            1
2     Target January          1350000                            2
3     Target February         20000000                           1
4     Target February         23500000                           2
5     Target January          1500000                            3
```

What I want to show is in codeigniter using sql query like

```
SELECT * FROM `target` WHERE `staff_id`='$id' ORDER BY 'id' DESC LIMIT 3,1
```

I have tried in codeigniter using get where,order by and limit query however the screen is going blank

Here's the model code

```
    $id=get_staff_user_id();
    $this->db->get_where('target', array('staff_id'=>$id,));
    $this->db->order_by('id','desc');
    $this->db->limit(3, 1);  
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query;
```

Here's the controller code

```
 $data['target'] = $this->target_model->getAllTarget()->result();
```

Here's the view code

```
 <?php foreach($targets as $target){ 
  if($total >= floatval($target->achievement)) {
                $percent = 100;
            } else {
                if ($total !== 0) {
                    $percent = number_format(($total * 100) / $target->achievement, 2);
                }
            }
  echo $percent;
 ?>
```

Where's the error in my code ?

Thank you

Comment: remove extra comma `$this->db->get_where('target', array('staff_id'=>$id));` after $id and enable error reporting to know what is the error.

Comment: *" however the screen is going blank"*  You mean PHP's white screen of death check the errorlog for a error.

Comment: *"remove extra comma $this->db->get_where('target', array('staff_id'=>$id)); after $id"* Will not help @DevsiOdedra, as using the comma there like the topicstarter did is in fact [valid](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bd84c248067a8c2a860984b78c245677346348ba) code and will not give a parse error..

Comment: ya its just suggestion, to know exact error enable error reporting.

Comment: `foreach($target as $target` replace targets to target  because you pass target from controller to view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is - `get_where()` returns already a DB Result Instance - in order to resolve your issue you have to do something like

```
return $this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from('target')
    ->where('staff_id', get_staff_user_id())
    ->order_by('id', 'desc')
    ->limit(3,1)
    ->get();
```

Comment: @Vickel - ofc it's the issue `get_where()` behaves like `get()` so in his case - he executes basically 2 queries - one only with the staff id as condition - and the second one with order by and limit but results in an error - because there is no from table (and if the option  `db_debug` is `false` - the site shows up blank)

Comment: ooops, I didn't see the second get(), sorry!

Answer (score 1):

In Model:

> Remove the extra comma

```
    $id=get_staff_user_id();
    $this->db->get_where('target', array('staff_id'=>$id));
    $this->db->order_by('id','desc');
    $this->db->limit(3, 1);  
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query;
```

In Controller:

> Change target to targets as in foreach it gets from same array name;

```
$data['targets'] = $this->target_model->getAllTarget()->result();
```

Comment: `array('staff_id'=>$id,)` is [valid](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bd84c248067a8c2a860984b78c245677346348ba) PHP code and will not give parser errors..

Comment: Yeah it's valid but for the safe side I just mentioned but the major problem on the `controller` side as name is different on `view`.

Comment: *"Yeah it's valid but for the safe side"* Using `array('staff_id'=>$id,)` is safe to use as it will [not](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/729f3e22743fe241425bd66e09d08338ffe8ac3f) generate a "ghost" element, which you might expect here when you read the code `array('staff_id'=>$id,)`.. But i agree using `array('staff_id'=>$id,)` looks a bit wierd..

Comment: Yes @RaymondNijland it looks wierd and Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: Hi @KamranKB I've tried and it's still not working, it's still blank in the screen

Comment: @IkramShabri have you checked that `get_staff_user_id();` this functions return id or not? It can be like `$this->get_staff_user_id();`

Comment: It's ok, what makes me weird is if the code just one line like return $this->db->get_where('target', array('staff_id'=>$id));  it's working fine